# question about string to file

Tags: c++

here is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream out("test", ios::out | ios::binary);

  if(!out) {
    cout << "Cannot open output file.\n";
    return 1;
  }

  double num = 100.45;
  char str[] = "www.java2s.com";

  out.write((char *) &num, sizeof(double));
  out.write(str, strlen(str));

  out.close();

  return 0;
}
```

i dont understand only this

```
out.write((char *) &num, sizeof(double));
```

why we need  `(char *)&num?`or `sizeof(double)?`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you can just use the stream insertion operator (`operator<<()`) in this case?  You wouldn't have to worry about such conversions by using it.

Comment: Unlike many of your other questions, this is the kind of question we can answer - fairly clear, real code - do I detect that there is more than one person using your account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write` takes two parameters, a `char*` and a length.

`&num` is actually a `double*`.  It's the value we want, but it's the wrong type, and the compiler would complain.  The `(char*)` tells the compiler to treat this as a `char*`.  Basically, it says to the compiler "Shutup. I know what I'm doing".

`sizeof(double)` is the size of the double in characters. (Usually, this is 8).

Together, they say to write the 8 bytes starting at the address given by &num. (or in other words, write out the bytes that make up num)

Comment: "is the size of the double in characters". No, it's the size in *bytes*.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, as the Standard requires that the `sizeof(char) ` == 1

Comment: The definition of "character" is not `char`. And how do we know you are even referring to `char`? You could be referring to `wchar_t` (which on most implementations is 4 bytes) or some other user-defined type that acts like a character. It is more unambiguous to say bytes because that is unit of measurement `sizeof` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You need them because you're accessing the component bytes that make up the `double`. `write` expects to receive a `char *`, so you cast the address to `char *`. Since it doesn't know the type of object being written (with the right cast, `write` will accept a pointer to almost anything), so you need to tell it how many bytes make up the object to be written.